# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) Invalid value for eu_vat Stripe payment gateway

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I code according to the stripe library and yet I have a 404 that comes out:

[Wed Nov 25 09:35:26. 2020] [php7: error] [pid 7014] [client ****] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request req _.....) Invalid value for eu_vat. \ N thrown in / home / http / data / https: //****.fr/wp-content/themes/sq/stripe-php-master/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php on line 38, referer: https: //****.fr / checkout /

```
 // STRIPE STRIPE STRIPE
<?php
    require_once('./stripe-php-master/init.php');

    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient("sk_test_--------");
    $curl = new \Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient([CURLOPT_PROXY => '*****:3128']);
    \Stripe\ApiRequestor::setHttpClient($curl);
    $address_line_1 = $_COOKIE["billing_address_1"];
    $phone = $_COOKIE["billing_phone"];
    $first_name = $_COOKIE["billing_first_name"];
    $last_name = $_COOKIE["billing_last_name"];
    $siret = $_COOKIE["billing_siret"];
    $TaxId = $_COOKIE["billing_TaxId"] ? $_COOKIE["billing_TaxId"] : ($_POST['TaxId'] ? $_POST['TaxId'] : NULL);
    $email = $_COOKIE["billing_email"];
   
    $cart = !empty($_COOKIE['cart']) ? $_COOKIE['cart'] : NULL;
     $billing_country = !empty($_COOKIE['billing_country']) ? $_COOKIE['billing_country'] : NULL;
    // $country = $_COOKIE["billing_country"];
    $company_name = $_COOKIE["billing_company"];
    // If Allemagne - Belgique - Autriche - Bosnie herzegovie - Russie - Suisse -> state mandatory
    $state = $_COOKIE["billing_state"];
    $post_code = $_COOKIE["billing_postcode"];
    $city = $_COOKIE["billing_city"];
    $stripe_token = !empty($_COOKIE['stripe_token']) ? $_COOKIE['stripe_token'] : NULL;
    // $stripe_token = $_COOKIE["stripe_tkn"];
    $arrival_date = !empty($_COOKIE['arrival_date']) ? $_COOKIE['arrival_date'] : NULL;
    // $arrival_date = $_COOKIE["arrival_date"];
    $engagement_period = !empty($_COOKIE['engagement_period']) ? $_COOKIE['engagement_period'] : NULL;
    // $engagement_period = $_COOKIE["engagement_period"];
    $monthly_frequency = !empty($_COOKIE['monthly_frequency']) ? $_COOKIE['monthly_frequency'] : NULL;
    // $monthly_frequency = $_COOKIE["monthly_frequency"];
    $quantity_office = !empty($_COOKIE['quantity_office']) ? $_COOKIE['quantity_office'] : NULL;
    // $quantity_office = $_COOKIE["quantity_office"];
    $parking_spot = !empty($_COOKIE['parking_spot']) ? $_COOKIE['parking_spot'] : NULL;
    // $parking_spot = $_COOKIE["parking_spot"];
    $price_str = $_COOKIE["price"];

    $created_customer = $stripe->customers->create([
        'address' => [
            'line1' => $address_line_1,
            'country' => $country,
            'state' => $state,
            'city' => $city,
        ],
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'metadata' => [
            'Periode_engagement' => $engagement_period,
            'Frequence_mensuelle' => $monthly_frequency,
            'Nombre_poste' => $quantity_office,
            'Place_parking' => $parking_spot,
        ],
        'name' => $company_name,
        'description' => $company_name,
        'invoice_settings' => [
            'custom_fields' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'SIRET',
                    'value' => 'FRAB123456789',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);

    $customer_id = $created_customer->id;

    $tax_id = $stripe->customers->createTaxId(
        $created_customer->id,
        [
            'type' => 'eu_vat',
            'value' => $TaxId,
        ]
    );

    $customer_card = $stripe->customers->createSource(
        $customer_id,
        ['source' => $stripe_token]
    );

    $engagement_number = (int) filter_var($engagement_period, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $final_price = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $price_str))) / $engagement_number;
    $price = $stripe->prices->create([
        'currency' => 'eur',
        'unit_amount' => $final_price,
        'recurring' => [
            'interval' => 'month'
        ],
        'product_data' => [
            'name' => 'NS Subscription'
        ]
    ]);

    $engagement_period_string = "first day of +".$engagement_number." month";
    $date = new DateTime('now');
    $nowTimestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    $date->modify('first day of next month');
    $firstDayOfNextMonthTimestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    // check month subscriptions for cancel date

    $date_end = new DateTime('now');
    $date_end->modify($engagement_period_string);
    $cancel_date_timestamp = $date_end->getTimestamp();

    $sub = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
        'customer' => $customer_id,
        'items' => [
            [
                'price' => $price->id
            ],
        ],
        'billing_cycle_anchor' => $firstDayOfNextMonthTimestamp,
        'cancel_at' => $cancel_date_timestamp
    ]);
?>
```

It works locally, but once online, under the same PHP version, we have a bug. I admit that I do not understand. If anyone has a solution opening?

Thank you all,

Comment: There is a lot of code there, and you haven't made it easier to read by including all that commented out stuff.  Have you checked/debugged the `$TaxId` value?  It seems to be set with a stacked ternary expression, which [the PHP docs warn against using](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) as it is easy to get wrong.  Are you sure that's working as expected?  [The Stripe docs say](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_tax_ids/create) the tax ID `value` is required, but that stacked ternary code seems to allow a `NULL`, which might explain the problem?

Comment: Probably whatever value you're passing for `$TaxId` is invalid in some way, like it's not a real VAT ID or it's malformed and doesn't match the formats at https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/tax-ids#supported-tax-id . I'd start by annotating your code to log exactly the value you pass.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that with the given stripe API version upgrade
https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-12-03, the behavior of tax IDs have changed

Check your local and beta stripe API version. If the versions are the same, enclose the createTaxId call in an InvalidRequestException try-catch block